# CodeIgniter not getting the resized image

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, resize

This is the code which I am trying to run..
I have stored the image in images folder whose path is: `C:\xampp\htdocs\ci\images`, and is at the same level at that of the application folder

```
public function display(){
    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = '/images/mypic.jpg';
    $config['new_image']='/images/re_mypic.jpg';
    $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config['width']    = 75;
    $config['height']   = 50;
    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();
}
```

I am not getting any error or something

Comment: Thank you...added the code you specified and got the errors. The path which I had specified was not correct. Just re-corrected the path and the code worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this and check your code errors

```
if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize()) {
    echo $this->image_lib->display_errors(); 
}
```